# Завершение цикла при вводе пустой строки Python

Tags: python

Хочу написать цикл do while на Python, который бы брал данные на ввод, до тех пор, пока я не введу пустую строку. Как это реализовать?

```
while True:
  x, y, z = map(int, input().split(' '))
  if input(''):
    break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def int_input():
    while True:
        try: yield int(input())
        except ValueError: break

x, y, *z = int_input()
```

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте:

```
while True:
    text = input()
    if not text:
        break

    x, y, z = map(int, text.split())
```

Answer (score 4):

Встроенная функция [`iter(function, end_value)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) вызывает переданную функцию `function()` до тех пор пока она не вернёт `end_value`.

```
for line in iter(input, ''):
    x, y, z = map(int, line.split())
    # use x, y, z here
```

В данном случае `input()` вызывается до тех пор пока пустая строка `''` не вернётся.